# Rendering buttons on form change

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a modular footer with some buttons and i want those buttons to only get rendered when someting on the form is changed. I have two forms, firstFormGroup and secondFormGroup. Any help?

My error message are handled like this:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="firstFormGroup.get('location').invalid">
                                            {{'csa.enter-value' | translate}}
                                        </mat-error>
```

And i was trying to do the same for my component.

```
<csa-savebar>
    <form class="form-bar" *ngIf="this.isChanged()">
        <button (click)="save(firstFormGroup)" class="btn btn-save">
            <mat-icon>check_circle</mat-icon>
            {{'csa.profile.save' | translate}}
        </button>
        <button (click)="discardChanges()" class="btn btn-discard">
            <mat-icon>highlight_off</mat-icon>
            {{'csa.profile.discard' | translate}}
        </button>
    </form>
</csa-savebar>
```

```
isChanged() {
    /* const controllersToCheck = [
      'location',
      'address',
      'postal',
      'city',
      'country',
      'category',
      'area',
      'phone',
      'website',
      'email',
      'isSelected',
      'from',
      'to',
      'splitedFrom',
      'splitedTo',
      'description',
    ]
    return controllersToCheck.some(ctrlName => {
      let firstCtrl = this.firstFormGroup.get(ctrlName)
      let secondCtrl = this.secondFormGroup.get(ctrlName)

      return (firstCtrl.dirty || firstCtrl.touched) && (secondCtrl.dirty || secondCtrl.touched)
    }) */
    return (this.firstFormGroup.dirty || this.firstFormGroup.touched) && (this.secondFormGroup.dirty || this.secondFormGroup.touched)
  }
```

```
private buildInitalFormGroup() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      location: ['', Validators.required],
      address: ['', Validators.required],
      postal: new FormControl('', ZipCodeValidation),
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      phone: ['', PhoneNumberValidation],
      area: ['+49', PhoneNumberPrefixValidation],
      country: ['Germany', Validators.required],
      category: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', EmailValidation],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      website: [
        '',
        Validators.compose([
          Validators.required,
          CustomValidators.patternValidator({
            invalidSite: true,
          }),
        ]),
      ],
      openHours: this.formBuilder.array(this.buildOpenHoursArray()),
    })

    this.secondFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      payments: ['', Validators.required],
    })

    this.categories = CategoriesArray()

    this.hours = OpenHoursArray()
  }
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined
    at ProfileFormComponent.push../src/app/features/profile/components/profile-form.component.ts.ProfileFormComponent.isChanged (

Comment: Where are you building your form? The error looks to me as if you are trying to access the FormGroup before it is created.

Comment: In the template you didnt bind the formgroup and if you can share the code when you create it in the ts.